# python requests.get() does not refresh the page

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have a piece of Python 3 code that fetches a webpage every 10 seconds which gives back some JSON information:

```
s = requests.Session()    

while True:
        r = s.get(currenturl)
        data = r.json()
        datetime = data['Timestamp']['DateTime']
        value = data['PV']
        print(str(datetime) + ": " + str(value) + "W")
        time.sleep(10)
```

The output of this code is:

> 2020-10-13T13:26:53: 888W
>
> 2020-10-13T13:26:53: 888W
>
> 2020-10-13T13:26:53: 888W
>
> 2020-10-13T13:26:53: 888W

As you can see, the DateTime does not change with every iteration. When I refresh the page manually in my browser it does get updated every time.

I have tried adding

```
Cache-Control max-age=0
```

to the headers of my request but that does not resolve the issue.

Even when explicitely setting everything to None after loop, the same issue remains:

```
while True:
        r = s.get(currenturl, headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'})
        data = r.json()
        datetime = data['Timestamp']['DateTime']
        value = data['PV']
        print(str(datetime) + ": " + str(value) + "W")
        time.sleep(10)
        counter += 1
        r = None
        data = None
        datetime = None
        value = None
```

How can I "force" a refresh of the page with requests.get()?

Comment: @Rakesh nope, same issue then.

Comment: I guess that's not possible, you need to run the `ajax call` with `setInterval` of certain duration and reload the page in an infinite loop or how many times ever you wanted.

Comment: `requests.get()` works in backend and the question you are asking is about the frontend. Try to find the solution from the frontend side.

Comment: @AjayA not sure what you mean to be honest. I thought the Python requests library just did a simple HTTP GET with the .get() method. I would expect the results to be the same when doing this in a "real" browser and using Python when using identical headers.

Comment: When you design an application, there will be 3 components

1. Backend
2. Database
3. Frontend.


Python is backend coding language. You have got the data using `requests.get()`. Now you must bring that to frontend, which is not done using python. Please discuss with your team and cross check, before spending more time here

Comment: @AjayA I understand that, but I kinda fail to see the relevance to my question here. I am not developing an application with a team. I am simply trying to scrape some information from a website which is not under my own control by using HTTP GET methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this particular website doesn't continuously refresh on its own, unless the request comes from its parent url.

```
r = s.get(currenturl, headers={'Referer' : 'https://originalurl.com/example'})
```

I had to include the original parent URL as referer. Now it works as expected:

> 2020-10-13T15:32:27: 889W
>
> 2020-10-13T15:32:37: 889W
>
> 2020-10-13T15:32:47: 884W
>
> 2020-10-13T15:32:57: 884W
>
> 2020-10-13T15:33:07: 894W